CORS Issue When Making Requests Between Subdomains in NestJS
NestJS application. I have set up a CORS middleware to handle allowed origins, but it seems like the requests from my frontend are being blocked.
I have two subdomains:

https://admin.x.io

https://adminapi.x.io


Here is my CORS configuration in the main.ts file
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { CorsMiddleware } from './cors.middleware';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.enableCors({
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
      const whitelist = [
        'https://admin.x.io',
        'https://adminapi.x.io'
      ];

      if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
        console.log("allowed cors for:", origin);
        callback(null, true);
      } else {
        console.log("blocked cors for:", origin);
        callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
      }
    },
    allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Accept',
    methods: 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS',
    credentials: true,
  });

  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();

Problem:
When I try to make a request from https://admin.x.io to https://adminapi.x.io/users/list, I receive a CORS error in the browser console indicating that the request is blocked. But I don't have this error in the login request
I expect to successfully retrieve the user list from https://adminapi.x.io without any CORS issues.
